# Glass Rendering has lots of black spots

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, glass

First post as a complete beginner. Following Blender Guru's Coffee cup tutorial. Modelled the cup, everything seems to be going well but my render output is rubbish and I'm struggling to fix it. I've spent the last 2 hours searching the net/spent 2 hours trying to sort the handle out. Lots of black spots/areas on the render:

[image]

If anyone can help these are my settings:

- Reflective Caustics On
- Refractive Caustics On
- Max Bounces 8
- Diffuse 4
- Glossy 4
- Transparency 8
- Transmission 8
- Volume 0
- Denoise On In Layers
  -I've upped Min Light Bounces & Min Transparent Bounces to 5 
  Normals facing the right way.
- Blender 2.80
- Cycles - GPU rendering
- Tried 256 / 512 rendering samples too.

I've even just created a new project, simple cone and set it to glass and same issue.

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  have your checked the normals?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird glass artifact](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/159641/weird-glass-artifact)

Comment: Hi. 

Can't upload but cxan link:

https://www.weddingphotographyselect.co.uk/CoffeCupAndPlate.blend

I'll check out the links above in the meantime.

Thank you.

p.s - Even if I create a new project and just add a cylinder and turn it to glass with the tuts method it's still the same.

Comment: Yes. Checked the normals and seemed fine.  Will check again.

Comment: Actually Checked the Normals on the cup and they were off. Fixed those but still not rendering right and normals are showing up as RED inside the cup but the outside is now all BLUE.

Adjusted the file

https://www.weddingphotographyselect.co.uk/CoffeCupAndPlate.blend

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm going back to the drawing board. Somebody else has pointed out that there are a lot of weird things going on with ma cup so back to the start I think.  Cheers anyway.